# Uri.parse with local ip address

Tags: java, android, browser

I'm trying to launch the Browser with an ip-address.

```
String url = "//192.168.178.1"
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

But instead of browsing the ip, the App crashes and I only get a "new tab" window on the browser.

Comment: you missed the schema. Change it to http: //192.168.178.1

Comment: Are you sure about that URL? Ie without http://?

Comment: crash => post stacktrace.

Comment: Ok, thank you.. adding "http://" worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed the schema for your url. Change it in `String url = "http://192.168.178.1"`